# Does url.parse protect against ../ in a url?

Tags: node.js, security

I want everything in a directory called `public` to be allowed to be served. What I have is:

```
let uri = require('url').parse(req.url).pathname;
let filePath = `${publicDir}/${uri}`;
// then simply check if the file exists.
```

Is the pathname property on the object returned by [url.parse](https://nodejs.org/api/url.html#url_url_parse_urlstring_parsequerystring_slashesdenotehost) protected against injection attacks? I don't know what they would all be. But for example attacks like `mysite.com/../../users/`.

Comment: I don't think `url.parse()` will do anything with `../` because it's a legal part of a URL path.  When you are turning it into file path, you can use `path.normalize()` to resolve any `..` segments before you combine it with the parent directory and that should keep it from traversing higher than you want.

Comment: Also, if you use Express, then `express.static()` can be configured to serve your static files and it has an option to prevent `../` access at all.